# sorting array and matching other array and getting error

Tags: c++, sorting, compiler-errors

I'm trying to write a program where I write information of people like: name,minutes and seconds.I need to sort people by the time. I can't understand how to sort minutes and dont lose other array sequence order- name and second. they just stay standing where they stood.Also I get error because something wrong with sort

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct people{
string name;
int min;
int sec;
};
int main()
{
 int temp;
struct people z[6];
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
   cin>>z[i].name;
   cin>>z[i].min;
   cin>>z[i].sec;
 }
sort(z.min,z.min +6);
cout<<endl;

for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
    cout<<z[i].name<<" "<<z[i].min<<" "<<z[i].sec<<endl;
 }
    return 0;
}


I am getting this error:
error: request for member 'min' in 'z', which is of non-class type 'people [6]'
```

Comment: `std::sort` expects 2 iterators, z is an array of `people` elements, you cannot access a member of that type on the array itself (look at your loops vs your call to sort)

Comment: my c++ is older than c++11. I am still confused. How should I write a code to work?

Comment: Your requirement `how to sort minutes and dont lose other array sequence order- name and second. they just stay standing where they stood` is impossible with `std::sort`. If you want to sort each item separately, use three different arrays.

Comment: @TheBEAst: Try something like `std::sort(z.begin(), z.end(), [](auto v, auto w) { return w.min*60+w.sec<v.min*60+v.sec;});`.

Comment: I meant when I sort minutes I want to every person information keep together(if minutes moves, then also moves person name and seconds)

Comment: @Aleph0 if I place this code instead of mine I get even more errors:error: request for member 'begin' in 'z', which is of non-class type 'people [6]'
error: request for member 'end' in 'z', which is of non-class type 'people [6]'
error: expected primary-expression before '[' token
error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
warning: C++0x auto only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x|
error: expected primary-expression before 'auto'|
warning: C++0x auto only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

std::sort() expects two iterators as parameters - the first one being the initial position of the sequence to be sorted and the second the final position. That's why your code does not compile.

In order to sort the array you either have to define an operator< in your class/struct or supply a comparison function as the third parameter to sort().

You could define an operator < as follows in the struct people:

```
bool operator < (const people &p)
{
    return min < p.min;
}
```

and call and cal sort like this:

```
sort(z, z + 6);
```

Alternatively you could define a function comp as follows (after the definition of struct people):

```
bool comp(const people &p1, const people &p2) { return (p1.min < p2.min); }
```

and call sort() like this:

```
sort(z, z + 6, comp);
```